# $\max(a,b)=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$ generalization

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am aware of an occasionally handy identity: $$\max(a,b)=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$$

However, I have found I'm unable to come up with a nice similar form for $\max(a,b,c)$. Of course I could always use the fact that $\max(a,b,c)=\max(\max(a,b),c)$ to write
$$\begin{align}\max(a,b,c)&=\frac{\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}+c+\left|\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}-c\right|}{2}
\\&=\frac{a+b+2c+|a-b|+|a+b-2c+|a-b||}{4}\end{align}$$

but this lacks elegance and in particular it is not clear to me just from the formula that if I permute the variables I get the same result.

The following doesn't work, but it would be nice if I could write $\max(a,b,c)$ in some form like
$$\frac{a+b+c+|a-b|+|a-c|+|b-c|}{3}$$

> Is there a good generalization of this to $n$ variables? That is given $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}$, is there a way to write $\max(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ in a clearly symmetric form using addition, subtraction, division, and the absolute value function?

Comment: So you want it only to be symmetric or you don't want to have an interlinked absolute value functions ?

Comment: For 3 variables, we could apply also to the other two pairs first, add and divide by $3$. We gt a longer expression, but it has obvious symmetry.

Comment: @Elaqqad The question in this respect is a bit open ended. I would certainly prefer a form that is both symmetric and without interlinked value functions, but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt If you want interlinked absolute value function you can do it by recurrence: $$\max{(S)}=\frac{1}{\binom{|S|}{2}}\sum_{a,b\in S} \max(\{\max(a,b)\} \cup S\backslash\{a,b\}) $$ this will give you an interliked absolute value but symmetric using addition , subtraction but I don't think it will be clear and I think it will be huge, I can conjecture that there is no a formula without interlinked absulate value

Comment: Yes, thanks AndréNicolas and Elaqqad for this method - it's a good point (though I am still hoping for something more compact even if it does necessitate interlinked absolute value functions).

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but thought it may be relevant: Assuming $x_k\geqslant0$, then by using the power mean: $$M_p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\left(\dfrac1n\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^p\right)^{1/p},$$ we can write $\max(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ as $$M_{\infty}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\lim_{p\to    \infty}M_p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\lim_{p\to       \infty}\left(\dfrac1n\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^p\right)^{1/p}.$$ Similarly, $M_{-\infty}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\min(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

Comment: We can write $\max(x,y,z)$ in  a more symmetric manner as: $$\frac{1}{12}\big(4S+\sum_{\rm cyc}|x-y|+\sum_{\rm cyc}|S+|x-y|-3z|\big),$$ where $S=x+y+z$.

Answer (score 6):

Symmetrizing in the obvious way:

$$\frac{a+b+c}3+\frac{|a-b|+|b-c|+|a-c|}{12}+\\\frac{|a+b-2c+|a-b||+|a+c-2b+|a-c||+|b+c-2a+|b-c||}{12}$$

For four variables, I found:

$$\tfrac14\left(a+b+c+d+|a-b|+|c-d|+|a+b-c-d+|a-b|-|c-d||\right)$$

Of course you don't *have* to use absolute value signs: $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[m]{a^m+b^m+c^m}$$

Comment: How large does $m$ have to be so that expression is within $\epsilon$ of the max?

Comment: nothing formal, but some simulations suggest $m=10$ does a good job

Comment: That's not easy to answer, but for two variables $a>b$, the error is roughly $\frac{a}{m}(\frac{b}{a})^m$. The closer they are, the worse.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this answer is in line with @Elaqqad's comment. It's true this formulation didn't occur to me before Elaqqad's comments, but I am holding out for something more elegant.

Comment: You might be interested in this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13253/nice-expression-for-minimum-of-three-variables

Comment: @AndrewWoods : Can you cite your reference for that error?

Comment: @MichaelChirico: Same for $m=10$, reference?

Comment: @abhinavjha this was >3 years ago but I imagine I just picked some values for a,b,c and started plugging away in R

Comment: @MichaelChirico I know it's an old post, but I am facing the same issues. That's why asked if you have read somewhere on the optimal choice of $m$.

Comment: definitely no... just played around on the computer a bit. I recommend you do the same if you're looking at an applied case instead of contemplating theory