# Maximum Proof (Average?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

The link here: [$\max(a,b)=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$ generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219291/maxa-b-fracaba-b2-generalization?noredirect=1&lq=1) shows that $\max(a,b)=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$.

> Is it true that $\max(|a|,|b|)=\frac{1}{2}(|a|+|b|)$?

Comment: $\max(|a|,|b|)=\frac12(|a|+|a|)$ or $\max(|a|,|b|)=\frac12(|b|+|b|)$ and one can conclude that $\max(|a|,|b|)=\frac12(|a|+|b|)$ is between those two value unless $|a|=|b|$ in which case all 3 are equal.

Answer (score 1):

$\max\{|a|,|b|\}=\frac{1}{2}(|a|+|b|)$ is wrong. Try $a=1$, $b=3$.

By the way, the following statement is true.
$$\max\{|a|,|b|\}\geq\frac{1}{2}(|a|+|b|).$$

Indeed, let $|a|\geq|b|$. We can do it because our inequality is symmetric.

Thus, $\max\{|a|,|b|\}=|a|$ and we need to prove that
$$|a|\geq\frac{1}{2}(|a|+|b|)$$ or
$$|a|\geq|b|,$$
which is our assuming.

Comment: Oh. What if it was $\geq$?

Comment: @user23899 If so then it will be true.

Comment: How is it true? I'm having a hard time seeing this without plugging in a bunch of numbers

Comment: @user23899 I added something. See now.

Comment: Can you add details on this as well: $\max\{|a|,|b|\}\geq\frac{1}{2}(|a+b|)$. How does this differ?

Comment: @user23899 I added again two hours before.

Answer (score 1):

As we already know, $$\max(a,b)=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}.$$
Therefore $$\max(|a|,|b|)=\frac{|a|+|b|+||a|-|b||}{2}.$$

So if $\max(|a|,|b|)=\frac12(|a|+|b|),$ then
\begin{align}
 \tfrac12(|a|+|b|)  &= \frac{|a|+|b|+||a|-|b||}{2} \\
&= \tfrac12(|a|+|b|) + \tfrac12(||a|-|b||).
\end{align}

Subtracting $\frac12(|a|+|b|)$ from both sides,
$$ 0 = \tfrac12(||a|-|b||), $$
which implies that $|a| = |b|.$
In other words, the *only* way your formula can work is when
you could pick either $|a|$ or $|b|$ and get the maximum value either way.