# Proving a Max inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Going off of this question: [Maximum Proof (Average?)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427321/maximum-proof-average) How can we prove that $max(|a|,|b|)\geq \frac{1}{2}(|a+b|)$?

Comment: first try to prove $\max(|a|,|b|)\geq (|a|+|b|)/2$, I guess.

Comment: @MANMAID I can prove that. How does this help?

Comment: How do the answers to the linked question fail to answer your question?  In particular, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2427379/468350) gives the entire argument!

Comment: $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$

Answer (score 0):

first for $|a|>|b|$
$$2max\{|a|,|b|\}=2|a|>|a|+|b| \to(\div 2) max\{|a|,|b|\}>\frac{|a|+|b|}{2}$$
second for $|a|<|b|$
$$2max\{|a|,|b|\}=2|b|>|b|+|a| \to(\div 2) max\{|a|,|b|\}>\frac{|a|+|b|}{2}$$
3rd for $|a|=|b|$
$$2max\{|a|,|b|\}=2|a|=2|b|=|a|+|b| \to(\div 2) max\{|a|,|b|\}=\frac{|a|+|b|}{2}$$ as a result we have $$ max\{|a|,|b|\}\geq\frac{|a|+|b|}{2} $$ we know $$|a|+|b|\geq |a+b|$$ so 
$$max\{|a|,|b|\}\geq\frac{|a|+|b|}{2} \geq \frac{|a+b|}{2} $$

Answer (score 0):

$(1/2)|x+y| \le (1/2)(|x| + |y|) \le$

$(1/2)( |x| + |y| +||x| - |y|| =$

$\max${$|x|,|y|$}.

Note :

$\max${$a,b$}$= (1/2)(a +b + |a-b|)$.