# Is there a known equation for max or min of a set?

Tags: matrix-equations, maxima-minima, absolute-value

I know that $\max(a,b) = \frac{a + b + |a-b|}2$ What I want is to formulate a similar equation generalizing larger sets: $max(a,b,c)$, $\max(a,b,c,d)$ etc. I tried doing the algebra for $\max(a,max(b,c))$ to see if a pattern would emerge but I'm having trouble simplifying.

I don't have a great understanding of algebraic transformations over absolute values. What I'm *really* hoping for is that there is already a known generalization for max or min of a set. Is there such an equation?

For context, this isn't academic. I'm trying to write a formula for a spreadsheet that will find me the max or min of each row of a matrix of ***unknown*** dimensions. It's not good enough to just copy a formula for each row. In Google Sheets/Excel you can do this using the function: ARRAYFORMULA which repeats a formula inside it over each member of an array, but only for scalar functions (IE I can't use the built in MAX and MIN functions in sheets). So for example, on a 2-column matrix of any length my formula is: ARRAYFORMULA((A:A+B:B±abs(A:A-B:B))/2).

Comment: Well, the formula you get for $\text{max}(a,\text{max}(b,c))$ *is* a formula for $\text{max}(a,b,c)$. Even without simplifying, it's a formula. So... what exactly are you asking?

Comment: There is already a function in Excel which will take the max of a group of arbitrary dimensions, so just take the maximums of each row and put that in a new column

Comment: I can't use MAX or MIN in the spreadsheet formula. This is kind of an advanced spreadsheet formula concern, so I was hoping not to get into it since that's not really what this site is *for*. For the time being, just take my word for it: I can't use MAX or MIN, I need to duplicate those functions through algebra.

Comment: For three variables: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1219291/42969.

Answer (score 1):

For $i$ variables $x_{1},x_{2}, \cdots ,x_{i} $
$$
\max(x_{1},x_{2}, \cdots ,x_{n})=\lim_{n \to \infty} {\left( {x_{1}}^{n}+ {x_{2}}^{n}+ \cdots + {x_{n}}^{n} \right)}^{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
Is true and can easily be proved so.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13254/42969

Comment: Well that is 100% the KIND of answer I was looking for! But I may need to brush myself up on limits to implement it. Thanks a million though!