# Alternate form of $(A \oplus B)^c$?

Tags: binary

What alternate forms are there of this equation?

$$(A \oplus B)^c$$

$A$ and $B$ are binary vectors / integers, $\oplus$ is the bitwise XOR operator, $c$ is a constant. For example:

$$(5 \oplus 7)^2 = ((1, 0, 1) \oplus (1, 1, 1))^2 = ((0, 1, 0))^2 = 2^2 = 4$$

By definition, it's the same as this:

$$(\sum ((a_i + b_i \bmod 2) \cdot 2^i))^c$$

Is there another formula which doesn't require an aggregate like $\sum$?

Comment: Gah! Don't use _set_ brackets $\{\cdots\}$ when you're talking about sequences! Sets don't have order, and don't distinguish between containing an element one or multiple times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to represent XOR of two decimal Numbers with Arithmetic Operators](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61556/how-to-represent-xor-of-two-decimal-numbers-with-arithmetic-operators)

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks! I edited to fix that

Comment: @AhmedS. I think that other question has to do with $A \bigoplus B$ not $(A \bigoplus B)^c$. Also, the answers all require $\sum$