# How to calculate Maximum or Minimum of two numbers without using if?

Tags: soft-question, functions

How to to calculate the maximim or minimum of two numbers without using "if" ( or something equivalant to that manner)?

The above question is often asked in introductory computer science courses and is answered using [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46939/maximum-and-minimum).

Now although it is not obvious, but using absolute value is also equivalant to using an if statement e.g. defining Max(a,b) = a if a>b else b;

Besides using limits, is there another way of finding the maximum or minimum of two numbers?

Comment: For me the absolute value is $\sqrt{a^2}$ for real numbers. I don't see an if here.

Comment: Damn, that answers it

Comment: [Even earlier](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13237)...

Comment: Extra points for the interview is to note that `sqrt(x*x)` is not a numerical overflow safe function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whether you need an `if` statement to take an absolute value depends on the format in which your numbers are stored. If you're using IEEE floating point numbers, you can take the absolute value by masking out the sign bit.

Comment: @AlexM. : this answer reduced a decisional problem into a mechanically computable problem, so that getting absolute value of a number is just process that can be applied using the representation method.

Answer (score 50):

If you let $a$ and $b$ be any two numbers then,

$$\max (a,b) = \frac{1}{2}( a + b + |a-b| )$$.

Comment: Very nice one...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46939/maximum-and-minimum

Comment: A proof would be awesome.

Comment: Those who read Spivak's calculus know this formula :)

Comment: the `abs()` function has an implicit `if`...

Comment: @Shloim not necessarily: `abs(x) = sqrt(x * x)`

Comment: `sqrt(x*x)` is not a numeric overflow safe method. `abs()` is implemented in GNU as `return i < 0 ? -i : i;`

Answer (score 11):

If $a$ and $b$ are both positive, then
$$
\max(a,b) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(a^n+b^n\right)^{1/n}.
$$

Comment: From where is this formula obtained?

Comment: I would also like to know it.

Comment: @Aatmaj : just assume a is grater than and divide and multiply a and take the limit. I was an exercise in the intermediate real  analysis.

Comment: @Cesare :check my comment to atmaj.

Answer (score 2):

$$ a = \frac{a + b + (a-b)((2(a-b)+1) mod 2)}{2}, a > b$$
or $$b$$ equals the same, if $$ b > a$$
Maximum

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one more formula that came from definition of discriminant of quadratic equation which is [valid for real](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=X%2F2%20%2B%20Y%2F2%20-%201%2F2%20sqrt%28X%5E2%20-%202%20X%20Y%20%2B%20Y%5E2%29&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22%20-%3E%20%7B%22Math%22%7D) numbers:

```
minimum(x,y) = (x+y-sqrt(x^2-2xy+y^2))/2
```

The source of origin:
https://github.com/ohhmm/openmind/blob/d24bd9e4c87265038d29eda475d03da391c38fd5/omnn/math/Valuable.cpp#L2449

Comment: that is same as $\max (
a,b) = \frac{1}{2}( a + b + |a-b| )$ , why they are reimplementing an already existing function?

Comment: It is min, not max. May be used for arbitrary differential coding and HPC kernels generation from its formula: https://github.com/ohhmm/generator/blob/main/generator/generator.cpp