# Definition of argument-based $\min$ and $\max$

Tags: number-theory, definition

When I say "argument-based", I mean $\min$ and $\max$ functions that take arguments, as opposed to the min and max of a function. For example: $\min(3,4,-2)=-2$, $\min(100,3)=3$, $\max(3,4,-2)=4$, etc.

Now, I wish to define $\max$ and $\min$ as some formula. I have found out that $\min(x_0,\ldots,x_n)=-\max(-x_0,\ldots,-x_n)$ (after some legwork), but this is not what I am looking for.

I have been working on this problem from time to time since December 2014. I do not think I can solve this on my own (otherwise, I might have already). Is this even possible? If so, then how?

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/arithmetic-function-to-return-lowest-in-parameter ?

Comment: @MartinR In part, yes; I was hoping for some formula that could extend to $n$ parameters.

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13253/nice-expression-for-minimum-of-three-variables.